# Jquery error- Is not a function (Rails 3)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Firstly my Jquery knowledge is very limited but am reading  and practicing to remedy this, so please bear with me if this is a really basic question. As the title states i am getting a error message within my rails app

```
  $(".share a").button is not a function
```

My application.js file contains this

```
  $(function() {

  $(".share a")
  .button()
  .click(function() {

    var a = this;

    // first set the title of the dialog box to display the folder name
    $("#invitation_form").attr("title", "Share '" + $(a).attr("folder_name") + "' with others");

    // a hack to display the different folder names correctly
    $("#ui-dialog-title-invitation_form").text("Share '" + $(a).attr("folder_name") + "' with others");

    // then put the folder_id of the share link into the hidden field "folder_id" of the invite form
    $("#folder_id").val($(a).attr("folder_id"));

    // the dialog box customization
    $("#invitation_form").dialog({
      height: 300,
      width: 600,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        // first button
        "Share": function() {
          // get the url to post the data to
          var post_url = $("#invitation_form form").attr("action");

          // serialize the form data and post it the url with ajax
          $.post(post_url, $("#invitation_form form").serialize(), null, "script");

          return false;
        },
        // second button
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
```

});

And my view page containds this to call the jquery ( I think)

```
  <div class="share">
        <%= link_to "Share", "#", :folder_id => folder.id, :folder_name =>       folder.nameunless @is_this_folder_being_shared %>
      </div>
```

Can anyone advise why I am getting this error as from what i can see it should be working, I.E. when i click a button labelled share I should get a popup window appear with my invitation form.

Any help appreciated as I am now stuck at this point

Answer (score 1):

You most likely forgot to include jQuery UI.

Besides that, HTML does not have an attribute called `folder_name` (or `folder_id`). Please do not invent custom attributes - if you want to store custom data, use the data attributes: `data-folder-name="whatever"` and then use `.data('folderName')` to access it via jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, though i do have the Jquery UI libary in my app. Would the attributes you have mentioned be causing an issue to prevent the popup working?

Comment: On second thoughts would it be that i have jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js and jquery-ui.js ( V 1.8.16) in the same directory?